# Docker PHP Nginx 404 Permission denied

Tags: php, linux, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I was working on a project developed with Docker on Windows. But when I continued working on it in my Linux machine, I'm getting the 404 Not Found nginx page.

[image]

Docker Compose logs on my webserver service says Permission denied

```
webserver    | 2020/03/14 10:05:29 [crit] 6#6: *1 stat() "/var/www/public/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: <my_ip_address>, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
webserver    | 2020/03/14 10:05:29 [crit] 6#6: *1 stat() "/var/www/public/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: <my_ip_address>, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
webserver    | 2020/03/14 10:05:29 [crit] 6#6: *1 stat() "/var/www/public/index.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: <my_ip_address>, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
webserver    | <my_ip_address> - - [14/Mar/2020:10:05:29 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:73.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0"
```

I tried running this on the app's directory on my host machine but the issue persists:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/my-app
```

Here's my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
#Docker Services
services:
  #PHP + Laravel Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    networks:
      - app-network
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini

  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - app-network
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/

  #MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: <password>
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - app-network
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

Here's the Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

# Change current user to www
USER www

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

I tried changing the line 42 on the Dockerfile to this but it doesn't help:

```
RUN chown -R www:www /var/www
```

I'm using:

- Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon (3.6.7) 64-bit
- Linux kernel 4.15.0-88-generic
- Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b7f0
- docker-compose version 1.25.4, build 8d51620a

EDIT: Additional info

```
$ docker-compose exec app ls -la /var/www
total 1076
drwx------  17 www  www    4096 Mar 14 11:05 .
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root   4096 Feb 26 11:59 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1 www  www     235 Mar 10 10:27 .editorconfig
-rw-rw-r--   1 www  www     983 Mar 13 10:26 .env
-rw-rw-r--   1 www  www     824 Mar 10 10:27 .env.example
drwx------   7 www  www    4096 Mar 14 11:05 .git
-rw-rw-r--   1 www  www     116 Mar 10 10:27 .gitattributes
-rw-rw-r--   1 www  www     175 Mar 10 10:27 .gitignore
-rw-rw-r--   1 www  www     187 Mar 10 10:27 .styleci.yml
-rw-rw-r--   1 www  www   34515 Mar 10 10:27 CHANGELOG.md
-rw-rw-r--   1 www  www    1206 Mar 14 11:05 Dockerfile
-rw-rw-r--   1 www  www    1597 Mar 13 20:28 README.md
drwx------   7 www  www    4096 Mar 13 17:18 app
-rw-rw-r--   1 www  www    1739 Mar 10 10:27 artisan
drwx------   3 www  www    4096 Mar 13 17:18 bootstrap
-rw-rw-r--   1 www  www    1731 Mar 13 15:08 composer.json
-rw-rw-r--   1 www  www  215207 Mar 13 15:10 composer.lock
drwx------   2 www  www    4096 Mar 13 17:18 config
drwx------   5 www  www    4096 Mar 13 17:18 database
-rw-rw-r--   1 www  www    1239 Mar 10 11:29 docker-compose.yml
drwx------   2 www  www    4096 Mar 13 17:18 mysql
drwx------   3 www  www    4096 Mar 13 17:18 nginx
drwx------ 711 www  www  102400 Mar 13 17:18 node_modules
-rw-rw-r--   1 www  www  456333 Mar 10 15:43 package-lock.json
-rw-rw-r--   1 www  www    1144 Mar 10 15:43 package.json
drwx------   2 www  www    4096 Mar 13 17:18 php
-rw-rw-r--   1 www  www    1168 Mar 10 10:27 phpunit.xml
drwx------   4 www  www    4096 Mar 13 17:18 public
drwx------   6 www  www    4096 Mar 13 17:18 resources
drwx------   2 www  www    4096 Mar 13 17:18 routes
-rw-rw-r--   1 www  www     584 Mar 10 10:27 server.php
drwx------   5 www  www    4096 Mar 13 17:18 storage
drwx------   4 www  www    4096 Mar 13 17:18 tests
drwx------  48 www  www   12288 Mar 13 17:18 vendor
-rw-rw-r--   1 www  www     553 Mar 10 10:27 webpack.mix.js
failed to resize tty, using default size
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fixed it! I just needed to run

```
find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 0775 '{}' \;
```

on the `app` container which sets all directories under /var/www (inclusive) to read-exec for group/other users.